# How to find the Game Matrix from the Game Tree

Tags: game-theory

I am quite interested in game theory and have been self-studying it recently. However, I encounter some problem in creating the game matrix when the the second player's choices are depended on first player.
Here is the example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6dGv.png)

I can conclude that:

For Player I has 2 strategies: t and b

For Player II, whose strategies depend on Player I
when I use t, II can: s, f, a;
when I use b, II can: w, e

As the result, the matrix will become like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZGIt.png)

So what can I do?